# Fetching only single row in table join from second table if two rows are possible

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Telephone`. This table has

```
tableId      milepost
100          11.5
```

I have another table `boundary` Which has

```
startMilePost  endMilePost    Supervisor
11             11.5           A
11.5           12             B
```

Now I am joining `telephone` and `boundary` on condition `table.milepost between boundary.startMilePost and boundary.endMilePost`

But for above scenario join returns two rows and I want only 1st one.
Please suggest how to write query for this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you don't actually want `between`, but combination of `>` and `<=` (because `between` includes both boundaries):

```
SQL> with
  2  telephone (tableid, milepost) as
  3    (select 100, 11.5 from dual),
  4  boundary (startmilepost, endmilepost, supervisor) as
  5    (select 11, 11.5, 'A' from dual union all
  6     select 11.5, 12, 'B' from dual
  7    )
  8  select *
  9  from telephone t join boundary b
 10    on t.milepost > b.startmilepost
 11   and t.milepost <= b.endmilepost
 12  /

   TABLEID   MILEPOST STARTMILEPOST ENDMILEPOST S
---------- ---------- ------------- ----------- -
       100       11,5            11        11,5 A

SQL>
```

---

Or, as you said you want to use `between` and select "the first row", then consider such an option: line #18 sets row number partitioned by `tableid` ordered by `startmilepost` in ascending order (if that's what you meant by "the first"):

```
SQL> with
  2  telephone (tableid, milepost) as
  3    (select 100, 11.5 from dual),
  4  boundary (startmilepost, endmilepost, supervisor) as
  5    (select 11, 11.5, 'A' from dual union all
  6     select 11.5, 12, 'B' from dual
  7    )
  8  select x.tableid,
  9         x.milepost,
 10         x.startmilepost,
 11         x.endmilepost,
 12         x.supervisor
 13  from (select t.tableid,
 14               t.milepost,
 15               b.startmilepost,
 16               b.endmilepost,
 17               b.supervisor,
 18               row_number() over (partition by t.tableid order by b.startmilepost) rn
 19        from telephone t join boundary b
 20          on t.milepost between b.startmilepost and b.endmilepost
 21       ) x
 22  where x.rn = 1;

   TABLEID   MILEPOST STARTMILEPOST ENDMILEPOST S
---------- ---------- ------------- ----------- -
       100       11,5            11        11,5 A

SQL>
```

Comment: Nope....there can be condition where we have only 11 - 11.5  or 11.5 - 12  row in that case it should be selected

Comment: Then what would you want to do? 11.5 belongs to both [11 - 11.5] and [11.5 - 12]. How to know which one to pick?

Comment: Just pick the first One, in that scenario

Comment: OK, but - what makes that row "the first one"? First by what?

Comment: I added another example which uses that "first row". Have  a look, please.